# update a variable in another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

hey everyone thanks for looking and hope you find an answer...im trying to update a highscore screen.
this is my adaptor

```
SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                listGeneral,
                R.layout.list_highscore_row,
                new String[] {"catGeneral","score1"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
        );
```

this fills my list

```
HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("catGeneral","Level 1");
        temp.put("score1", String.valueOf(hScoreGen1) + "/10");
        listGeneral.add(temp);
```

i want to change the value of `hScoreGen1` if it is lower then the new score...
so far i have this in another activity that should change the value of hScoreGen1

```
if (totalCorrect > ScoreScreen.currentScoreCatValue){  //currentScoreCatValue is the orginal value of hScoreGen1
                            if (currentScoreCat == 1){   //currentScoreCat is set to 1 from another activity
                                HighScores.hScoreGen1 = totalCorrect;
```

my problem seems to be with the listviews not displaying the changed values instead showing the onCreate Values...hope you can help
and i can add more code if needed

Comment: You have to refresh the listview? notifyDataSetChanged(). More information [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) also make sure that you call it from the Main UI thread.

Comment: Call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: update your HashMap and SimpleAdapter using notifydatachanged()

Comment: Don't make your adapter static, possible leaks may occur. Instead implement the Broadcast and receiver to implement this, or listeners.

Comment: @jitain can u give me code example, im not sure how to call the adapter from the other activity other then by static

Comment: For listener just create an interface, implement this over the Activity where you want to update the score. Set this listener object in the base activity [apply the null check] and set the listener while from second activity.

Comment: kewl ill try that, if you add code to the answers i can tick your answer

Comment: im still learning but appreciate the direction you have pointed me too

Answer (score 0):

update your adapter

```
    if (totalCorrect > ScoreScreen.currentScoreCatValue){  //currentScoreCatValue is the         orginal value of hScoreGen1
                        if (currentScoreCat == 1){   //currentScoreCat is set to 1 from another activity
                            HighScores.hScoreGen1 = totalCorrect;
                            HighScores.adapter1.notifydatachanged();
```

Comment: sorry karthick notifydatachanged(); causes The method notifydatachanged() is undefined for the type SimpleAdapter error and asks to change to notifydatasetchanged() which doesnt work either

Comment: can i easily change the simple adapter

Comment: public void setNewHighScore(){
  
                     if (totalCorrect > ScoreScreen.currentScoreCatValue){   caused a nullpointerexemption
                      
                       HighScores.hScoreGen1 = totalCorrect;
                       HighScores.adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      
                     }
 }